# Письма от sendmail отклоняются некоторыми почтовыми серверами

Tags: sendmail

Здравствуйте!

Всех с наступающим Новым годом! Прошу помощи по такому вопросу: установил себе на DigitalOcean движок для блога [Эгея](http://blogengine.ru/) по инструкции из этого блога «[Как завести Эгею на DigitalOcean](http://blog.antoniokov.com/all/blogengine-on-digitalocean/)», но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что движок при публикации в блоге комментариев от пользователей не отправляет письма, тогда я вспомнил, что за транспорт писем может отвечать такая простая штука как `sendmail`, установил его, но ничего не настраивал. Оставил тестовый комментарий и получил на свой ящик (Google Apps) письмо, но когда решил ответить на этот комментарий, то на почту Mail.ru sendmail уже ничего отправить не смог. Я заглянул в файл `mail.log` по пути `/var/log`, и там увидел следующее:

```
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29559]: gethostbyaddr(188.166.17.115) failed: 1
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29559]: gethostbyaddr(10.18.0.5) failed: 1
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29559]: alias database /etc/mail/aliases rebuilt by root
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29559]: /etc/mail/aliases: 0 aliases, longest 0 bytes, 0 bytes total
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29666]: gethostbyaddr(188.166.17.115) failed: 1
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29666]: gethostbyaddr(10.18.0.5) failed: 1
Dec 30 22:55:03 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29668]: starting daemon (8.15.2): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Dec 30 22:58:33 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29831]: uBUMwWfQ029831: from=www-data, size=709, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201612302258.uBUMwWfQ029831@egeya-u$
Dec 30 22:58:33 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29832]: uBUMwX0E029832: from=<www-data@egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3.localdomain>, size=972, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=$
Dec 30 22:58:33 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29831]: uBUMwWfQ029831: to=sergey@pisma.ws, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=$
Dec 30 22:58:33 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29834]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SH$
Dec 30 22:58:33 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29834]: uBUMwX0E029832: to=<sergey@pisma.ws>, ctladdr=<www-data@egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3.localdomain> (33/33), de$
Dec 30 23:05:28 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29867]: uBUN5Sp4029867: from=www-data, size=468, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201612302305.uBUN5Sp4029867@egeya-u$
Dec 30 23:05:28 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29868]: uBUN5S9T029868: from=<www-data@egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3.localdomain>, size=731, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=$
Dec 30 23:05:28 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sendmail[29867]: uBUN5Sp4029867: to=zapara@mail.ua, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=r$
Dec 30 23:05:28 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29870]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mxs.mail.ru., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Dec 30 23:05:29 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29870]: uBUN5S9T029868: to=<zapara@mail.ua>, ctladdr=<www-data@egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3.localdomain> (33/33), del$
Dec 30 23:05:29 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29870]: uBUN5S9T029868: uBUN5T9T029870: DSN: Service unavailable
Dec 30 23:05:30 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[29870]: uBUN5T9T029870: to=<www-data@egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3.localdomain>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mail$
Dec 30 23:17:19 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[1627]: gethostbyaddr(188.166.17.115) failed: 1
Dec 30 23:17:19 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[1627]: gethostbyaddr(10.18.0.5) failed: 1
Dec 30 23:17:19 egeya-ubuntu-512mb-ams3 sm-mta[1634]: starting daemon (8.15.2): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
```

Как понимаю, на домен pisma.ws письмо прошло, но вот на стороне Mail.ru письмо не прошло верификацию и было отклонено их сервером.

У меня мало знаний в этих вопросах, поэтому, может кто-то из специалистов в этой области сможет мне посоветовать какое-то решение для моей проблемы, или может в настройках домена для моего блога можно добавить какие-то DNS-записи, чтобы письма не попадали в спам и не отклонялись почтовыми серверами.

Comment: Немного погуглив, удалось найти такую заметку «[Памятка по настройкам почты](https://skurudo.ru/all/mail-server-setting-memo/)». Человек использует движок «Эгея», но, к сожалению, мне непонятно как проделать всё то, что он описывает в своём материале. Может кто-то сможет подсказать?

Comment: я бы не назвал sendmail простой штукой. pisma.ws - это ваш домен?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да, домен принадлежит мне. Блог на другом домене

Comment: какой обратный адрес у писем, что вы отправляете с сервера?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, движок Эгея подставляет в поле "От" адрес blog@inotes.pp.ua, но Mail.ru, да и другим почтовым серверам, просто не хватает каких-то дополнительных настроек с моей стороны, чтобы это всё заработало правильно.

Comment: inotes.pp.ua ваш домен?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да, там крутится блог, просто не хотел давать ссылку, чтобы не посчитали рекламой.